# Djangoを使っているのですが、formとHTMLの関係でハマりました。。

Tags: python3, html, django, form

Djangoは初学者で、勉強しながらWebアプリ開発をしています。
旅行サイトの検索条件を打ち込むようなページを作っているのですが、formを作成し、テンプレートに反映させようとしたところ、下の画像のように上手くテンプレートを引っ張ってこれません。
どこに問題があるか試行錯誤しながら修正してますが改善ならず。。
どなたかご教授よろしくお願いいたしますm(_ _)m

## travel/travel_app/forms.py

```
from django import forms

class ConditionForm(forms.Form):
    #start = '固定'

    goal = forms.CharField(label='目的地', max_length=30, required=True,)

    people = forms.ChoiceField(label='人数', choices=PEOPLE,
                               widget=forms.Select, required=True,
                               help_text='※必須',)

    age = forms.CharField(label='年齢',required=True,
                          help_text ='※必須',)

    sex = forms.ChoiceField(label='性別',choices=SEX,
                            widget=forms.Select, required=True,
                            help_text ='※必須',)

    def clean_people():
        cleaned_data = super().clean_people()
        people = cleaned_data.get('people')
        if not people:
            raise forms.ValidationError('入力してください。')
        return cleaned_data

    def clean_age():
        cleaned_data = super().clean_age()
        people = cleaned_data.get('age')
        if not age:
            raise forms.ValidationError('入力してください。')
        return cleaned_data

    def clean_sex():
        cleaned_data = super().clean_sex()
        sex = cleaned_data.get('sex')
        if not sex:
            raise forms.ValidationError('入力してください。')
        return cleaned_data
```

## travel/travel_app/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
from . import forms
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from .forms import ConditionForm

def index(request):
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'travel/condition.html',
                        {'index': index},)

def condition_form(request):
    form = ConditionForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

context = {'form' : form}
return render(request, 'travel/condition.html', context)
```

## travel_app/templates/travel/condition.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
    {{ index }}<br>
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action='/form/' method='POST'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}<br>
        <input type="submit" value="送信">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

## 現在の出力ページ

[image: 現在の出力ページ]

Comment: 単に`{{ form.as_p }}<br>`の後ろの`<br>`を削除してみるとか。[Django、フォームの表示方法まとめ](https://narito.ninja/blog/detail/98/), [Django フォームの基本](https://python.keicode.com/django/form-basic.php)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！<br>は特に影響を及ぼしていないようです。。

Comment: 他には`forms.py`や`view.py`で閉じ括弧`)`の直前のカンマ`,`を削除してみるとか？

Comment: すべて取り除きましたがダメでした。。

Comment: 後は動くサンプルを元に改造を試してみて経験を積むとか？

Comment: 試行錯誤してみます。。

Answer (score 0):

```py
def index(request):
    form = ConditionForm()
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'travel/condition.html',{'index': index, 'form':form})
```

`index`メソッドの`return`に`form`をcontextとして渡す必要があるのではないでしょうか？
おそらく「現在の出力ページ」は`condition_form`ではなく`index`メソッドが返している結果のように見えます。

Comment: なるほど！ありがとうございますm(_ _)m